# String join function C

Tags: beginner, c

```
char* join(char** strings, size_t num_strings, char* seperator)
{
    int cache = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++){
        cache += strlen(strings[i]);
    }
    char * joined = malloc((cache + num_strings * strlen(seperator) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    for(int j = 0; j < num_strings; j++){ //big loop
        if(j != 0){
            int j = 0;
            while(j < strlen(seperator)){ //inserting seperators
                joined[count] = seperator[j];
                count++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        int insert_string = 0;
        while( insert_string < strlen(strings[j])){ //inserting strings
            joined[count] = strings[j][insert_string];
            insert_string++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    joined[count] = 0; //Zero Termination
    return joined;
}
```

I wrote this `join()` function, which creates a string from `num_strings` with specified separator, for example `*`. Is there a way to make this more concise?  Also is the termination correct?

Comment: Are you purposely avoiding `strcat` and `memcpy`?

Comment: idk of strcat and memcpy im new to c :D

Comment: There are two aspects lacking. Without going into too much detail, they are tests and documentation. Tests (consider Test-Driven Development/TDD) make sure your code behaves as expected even in corner cases. Documentation is mostly prose that tells the user of that function what its behaviour is and what its requirements are (preconditions and postconditions). Without documenting these guarantees, you often can't tell whether something is right or wrong.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> char* join(char** strings, size_t num_strings, char* seperator)
> ```

The inputs can be `const` as they should not be modified by this function: `const char* join(const char** strings, size_t num_strings, const char* seperator)`

---

> ```
> int cache = 0;
> ```

`cache` is not a very descriptive name. Prefer `input_strings_length` or similar

---

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++){
> ```

Format as `for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {` (added spaces for readability)

---

> ```
> char * joined
> ```

Why does the `*` have spaces around both side, but the rest are `char* name`? (space only on right side)

---

> ```
> for(int j = 0; j < num_strings; j++){
>     if(j != 0){
>         int j = 0;
> ```

Prefer not using shadowed variables (same variable name in both inside and outside)

---

> ```
> int j = 0;
> while(j < strlen(seperator)){ //inserting seperators
>     joined[count] = seperator[j];
>     count++;
>     j++;
> }
> ```

This is same as:

```
strcpy(joined + count, seperator);
count += strlen(seperator);
```

which I find more readable

---

> ```
> // big loop
> ```

This comment is not descriptive at all. What does it mean?

I would rename variable in `for(int j = 0; j < num_strings; j++){` to be `for (int string_index = 0; string_index < num_strings; string_index++) {`

---

The whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * array[] = {
    "First entry",
    "Second entry",
    "Third entry",
};

const char* join(const char** strings, size_t num_strings, const char* seperator) {
    int input_strings_length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {
        input_strings_length += strlen(strings[i]);
    }

    size_t string_length = input_strings_length + num_strings * strlen(seperator);
    char* joined = malloc((string_length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    joined[string_length] = '\0';

    int array_offset = 0;

    for (int string_index = 0; string_index < num_strings; string_index++) {
        if (string_index != 0) {
            strcpy(joined + array_offset, seperator);
            array_offset += strlen(seperator);
        }

        strcpy(joined + array_offset, strings[string_index]);
        array_offset += strlen(strings[string_index]);
    }

    return joined;
}

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", join(array, 3, "SEP"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably worth `const size_t sep_len - strlen(separator);` rather than calling `strlen()` _n_ times.

Comment: Why `int string_length`?   `size_t string_length` would less likely overflow.

Comment: `string` should be `const` on both levels, so `char const* const* string`. I'd also always (for consistency) put the `const` to the right of what is not modifyable.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>     char * joined = malloc((cache + num_strings * strlen(seperator) + 1)
>                            * sizeof(char));
> ```

Trivial (spelling): sep**a**rator.

Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` (which is 1, by definition) is pointless.

We only need to reserve space for `num_strings - 1` separators.

The bigger issue here is that we dereference `joined`, *even when `malloc()` returns a null pointer*.  That's Undefined Behaviour.

```
char * joined = malloc(cache + (num_strings - 1) * strlen(separator) + 1);
if (!joined) {
    /* allocation failed - pass null pointer back to caller */
    return joined;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**`const`**

Use `const` to allow greater uses of `join` and employ select optimizations.

**Paradigm shift**

C2X promotes size before pointer

**Avoid running down the strings multiple times to find the length.**

One pass of `size_t length_separator = strlen(separator); ...  size_t len = strlen(string[i]);` is sufficient to know the length.

**Check for overflow**

Not too hard to add basic length checking.

---

Some unchecked code.

```
#define JOIN_N 64

char* join(size_t num_strings, const char** strings, const char* separator) {
  // Efficiently handle first strings.
  size_t lengths[JOIN_N];

  // Find separator length
  size_t length_separator = strlen(separator);
  if (num_strings && SIZE_MAX/num_strings >= length_separator) {
    return NULL; // Too big;
  }

  // Find total size
  size_t size_needed = 1 + num_strings*length_separator;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {
    size_t len = strlen(string[i]); 
    if (i < JOIN_N) {
      lengths[i] = len;  // Save for later
    }
    if (SIZE_MAX - size_needed > len) {
      return NULL;  // Too big
    }
    size_needed += len;
  }

  // Allocate
  char *joined = malloc(size_needed);
  if (joined == NULL) {
    return NULL;  // Too big, OOM
  }

  // Copy
  char *offset = joined;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      strcpy(offset, separator);
      offset += length_separator;
    }
    size_t len = (i < JOIN_N) ? lengths[i] : strlen(strings[i]);
    strcpy(offset, strings[i]);
    offset += len;
  }

  join[offset] = '\0';
  return join;
}
```

---

Also research using `memcpy()` or non-standard [`stpcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stpcpy.3.html) instead of `strcpy()`.